# Why doesn't Multiprocessing use 100% CPU in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, python-multithreading, joblib

I have to run some code in parallel and, while it uses 100% of the CPU in my local computer, it doesn't work like that in Google Compute Engine.

I'm using a Compute Engine with 24vCPUs and 22Gb memory. The following image shows the utilization of CPU while the program is running.

[image: CPU utilization below 0,15%]
The mock code I'm using is:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing 

def some_function():
       num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # = 24
       salida = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(hijo.calcula_error)(metodo='pond') for hijo in self.descendencia)
```

Where hijo.calcula_error is a function that can be run in parallel.

Is this behaviour normal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Wild guess: looks to me like intentional performance limiting to operate at peak efficiency instead of top speed... might seem strange to us but if you're running gazillions of cores at the same time this might be a good idea to keep the power consumption on a reasonable level.

Comment: Might be... But why do they let me have 24 cores then?

Comment: Because those are 24x as fast as one core running at the same level? i dunno x)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it also depends very much on your code, I would review the [multiprocessing methods](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#contexts-and-start-methods) and start testing by run it on a single core instance to see if it uses all the capacity (or maybe spawn 24 process on a 24 core instance). I hope this can help.

Other thing I would consider here is take a look on the memory bottleneck or disk I/O throttling that could be limiting the over all performance of the instance.